# How to center align a table in Bookdown using the R kableExtra package?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown, kableextra

I am using RStudio with a Bookdown template and am trying to place my table in the middle of the page. I am using the `position` command as per the example code [developer's page](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html) to center-align the table. Upon knitting to HTML, the table remains left-aligned.

This is what I tried at first:

````
```{r table-test, echo = FALSE}

# To get started
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]

# Now to the example...
# Note that the position is not the default "left" but rather "center"
kable(dt) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = F, position = "center")```
````

I also tried placing `<center>` before the R chunk and `</center>` afterwards. In both cases, the table remains left-aligned. In addition, the `full_width = T` command does not make a difference as the table remains as before.

This is the YAML header:

```
title: "Integration"
author:
- Nitram
date: "updated on `r Sys.Date()`"
output: bookdown::pdf_book
bibliography: EC-biblio.bib
always_allow_html: yes
description: Nitram
documentclass: book
github-repo: https://gitlab.uni.edu/
link-citations: yes
biblio-style: apalike
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
advisor: Advisor
unitname:
  faculty: School
  institute: Institute
  laboratory: Lab
preface: |
  `r paste(readLines("_00-preface.Rmd"), collapse = '\n  ')`
abstract: |
  `r paste(readLines("_00-abstract.Rmd"), collapse = '\n  ')`
resume: |
  `r paste(readLines("_00-resume.Rmd"), collapse = '\n  ')`
acknowledgements: |
  `r paste(readLines("_00-acknowledgements.Rmd"), collapse = '\n  ')`
```

How can I center-align my table?

---

PS: since this may be a bug, I have reported it [here](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/465).

Comment: What is your YAML header?

Comment: @J_F  YAML header is now included in the post.